# Can calcium sulphate substitute for calcium chloride in mozarrella cheese making?

Tags: substitutions, mozzarella

Calcium sulphate is what I have plenty.

Comment: I have no idea about your production. Private I would guess. But as an info 1) calcium sulphate has been used to impart at least a nice white color to mozzarella and similar products and 2) can qualify as adulteration. At least it should not have very deleterious health effects ;) assuming is of pharmaceutical or food grade.

Answer (score 3):

Calcium sulphate (CaSO<sub>4</sub>.*n*H<sub>2</sub>O) is also known as gypsum or plaster of Paris. It's slightly soluble in cold water (~ 3 g/l) and almost insoluble in hot water. Calcium chloride (CaCl<sub>2</sub>) is much more soluble (~ 800 g/l).

So if you need more than about 2 g/l of calcium chloride, the replacement won't work as you just can't dissolve enough of the sulphate. Also, any lumps of calcium sulphate risk solidifying in a fairly short time, depending on which form you planned on using: plaster (hemihydrate, solidifies when wetted) or ground gypsum (dihydrate).

(That's of course assuming you can get food grade calcium sulphate, technical grades are not necessarily safe for food use)

Comment: The real question is whether calcium sulphate will even work for strengthening the milk structure. I've never read anything about it being used for that purpose.

Comment: Because it won't dissolve sufficiently: there's a competition between the milk proteins and the sulphate for the calcium, the sulphate wins.